# Printing result of a conversion to a textbox in JavaScript & HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to learn some JavaScript and currently I want to print a value of user input then print it to a textbox that I have.

In the console it works but it doesnt print anything to my gui.

code

```js
function converter() {
  result = document.getElementById("converted");
  var to_convert = document.getElementById("to_convert").value;
  var unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;
  var converted = 0;

  //Fahrenheit till celsius
  if (unit = "F") {
    var converted = 1.8 / to_convert;
  }

  // Cup till liter
  if (unit = "cup") {
    var converted = 0.236 * to_convert;
  }

  //lb till kg
  if (unit = "lb") {
    var converted = 0.454 * to_convert;
  }
  result.textContent.value = converted;
  console.log(converted);


  // (F - 32) / 1.8 = Celsius
  // cup * 0.236 = liter
  // lb * 0.454 = kg
}
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="to_convert" value="" size="5" /><br/>
    <select id="unit">
      <option value="F">Fahrenheit to Celcius</option>
      <option value="cup">cup to liters</option>
      <option value="lb">lb/pound to kg</option>
    </select>
    <input onclick="converter()" value="Konvertera" type="button" />
    <input type="text" id="converted" value="[resultat här]" size="15" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

code

Comment: You don't use `.textContent` if you're assiging to `.value`. `.textContent` is for text elements, `.value` is for inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace
`result.textContent.value = converted`
by
`result.value = converted`

```
 result.value = converted;
```

And It will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong! :  `result.textContent.value = converted` 
The right one is : `result.value = converted`

```js
function converter() {
  result = document.getElementById("converted");
  var to_convert = document.getElementById("to_convert").value;
  var unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;
  var converted = 0;

  //Fahrenheit till celsius
  if (unit = "F") {
    var converted = 1.8 / to_convert;
  }

  // Cup till liter
  if (unit = "cup") {
    var converted = 0.236 * to_convert;
  }

  //lb till kg
  if (unit = "lb") {
    var converted = 0.454 * to_convert;
  }
  result.value = converted;
  console.log(converted);


  // (F - 32) / 1.8 = Celsius
  // cup * 0.236 = liter
  // lb * 0.454 = kg
}
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="to_convert" value="" size="5" /><br/>
    <select id="unit">
      <option value="F">Fahrenheit to Celcius</option>
      <option value="cup">cup to liters</option>
      <option value="lb">lb/pound to kg</option>
    </select>
    <input onclick="converter()" value="Konvertera" type="button" />
    <input type="text" id="converted" value="[resultat här]" size="15" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign it like this: `result.value = converted`

```
result.value = converted
```